# Google and Facebook APIs are not working with signed apk inspite of correct hash key

Tags: android, facebook, hash

After generating the singed apk Facebook API is not working (google API was also returning null but somehow it is not giving that problem now). I have tried to generate the apk from two different keystore files and displayed the hash key in log.I wrote two same log lines but both have different hash keys.First line is different for both apks but the 2nd is same.May be the 2nd one is of the allies file as allies is same for both the apks. I have tried many solutions but no gain. 
Note: apk is working fine when I directly run the app from computer instead of installing the singed apk file. And I have added all the hash keys at facebook project that these apks show independently.

Comment: Have you insert your release has-key into your Facebook Developers account - in the settings section of your facebook app?

Comment: yes, I have inserted it into Facebook developers account.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your release keystore to your application in developer console.